# Strange formula for the dimension of a certain space of noncommutative polynomials

Tags: lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

Consider a vector space $V_r(n)$ spanned by (noncommutative) monomials  in variables $x_1,\ldots,x_r$
$$
 x_{1}^{n_1}x_{2}^{n_2}\ldots x_{r}^{n_r}
$$
of total degree $n.$ Inside this space consider a subspace $\text{Inv}_r(n)$ of *invariant* polynomials. A polynomial $P\in V_r(n)$ is called invariant if the difference
$$
P(x_1+t,x_2+t,\ldots,x_r+t)-P(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_r)
$$
is equal to zero modulo shuffle product ш.

Here is an example. The space $\text{Inv}_3(2)$ is spanned by polynomials $x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2$ and $x_1x_2+x_2x_3-x_1x_3.$ In the last case we have
$$
(x_1+t)(x_2+t)+(x_2+t)(x_3+t)-(x_1+t)(x_3+t)-(x_1x_2+x_2x_3-x_1x_3)
$$
$$
=tx_2+x_2t+t^2=t \ ш \left(x_2+\frac{1}{2}t\right).
$$

**Question.** I can show (via a terrible brutal force argument) that
$$
\text{dim}(\text{Inv}_r(n))= \sum_{i=0}^n {r-1 \choose i}.
$$
I would love to see a nice proof and an explanation of this result. Also, it will be interesting to have a nice basis of  $\text{Inv}_r(n).$

Comment: How does $x_1x_2+x_2x_3-x_1x_3$ live in the span of monomials with nondecreasing exponent?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a mistake.

Comment: @SamHopkins I corrected: the condition on exponents is not needed. But it is important that the variables go in “correct” order.

Comment: It feels like it could be related to matroids; specifically that number is the number of independent sets of the uniform matroid. In other words, if you choose r-1 generic points in n space, how many subsets are independent.